# HttpSelfHostServer use prefixes like HttpListener

Tags: c#, self-hosting, httplistener, self-host-webapi

There is `Prefixes` field in `HttpListener`. You can add some string like "http://+:8080/" and your application just process all queries to 8080 port.

I have `HttpSelfHostServer` it can use only valid Uri string like input to it `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` class. I want to get same behaviour in my `HttpSelfHostServer` like in `HttpListener` with prefixes like:

> http://+:8080/
>
> http://*:8080/
>
> http://some.url:8080/
>
> And so on...

```
...
var configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(prefix)
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localhost gets rewritten to `+` in this case, so `localhost:8080`, `0.0.0.0:8080`, `127.0.0.1:8080` should all work in the case you want to listen on all interfaces.

In the case where you ***don't*** want this automatic re-writing to happen, The second argument for `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` takes a `HostNameComparisonMode` which can be set to `Exact`.

Comment: so, `http://+:8080/` is equal to `http://localhost:8080/`, `http://*:8080/` is equal to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` and `http://some.url:8080/` is equal to `127.0.0.1:8080`.
And for every of 3 cases what kind of `HostNameComparisonMode` I should use? I know: `Exact`, `StrongWildcard` and `WeakWildcard`, but don't know which one to use for which case?

Comment: When I try to use `http://+:8080/` I get an error `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed`

Comment: @Max: that's the point of this question and answer. you can't use `http://+:8080` because it's not a valid URI, but you can use the solution in my answer instead.